# String pattern in web view

Tags: java, string

How to create String which includes two words and space between the. I meen I have text like this for example: The crush was on ul. Boczna and also on ul. Sucha.
And what i want to do I want make a String that would match for example "ul. Boczna"and "ul. Sucha"

I tried this:

```
String street = "ul" + " " + "[a-zA-Z]+"
```

But it doesnt work as I want.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't taking into account the period. To search for a period in a regex expression, use `"\."`

Try `"ul\.\s[a-zA-Z]+"` or `"ul\.\s\w+"`

If the period isn't always there, try `"ul\.?\s\w+"`

Comment: I'm getting an error: Illegal character in string literal.

Comment: In java, you need to double-escape backslashes. Try this: `"ul\\.\\s[a-zA-Z]+"`